# How to avoid spacing in the start and end of Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I don't want a circular gallery, but instead I don't want to show the free space in the left and right end of the gallery? Is there any possible way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to try [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). Its not that good as other android components but proves to be worth in most of the cases

> Horizontal ListView implementation has
>   the following features:
>
> ```
> Subclass AdapterView so I can make use of adapters
> Fast – make use of recycled views when possible
> Items are clickable – (accepts AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)
> Scrollable
> No center-locking
> ```