# How to implement screenshots gallery like Google Play?

Tags: android, gallery, google-play, horizontalscrollview

I'm wondering how to implement gallery of screenshots like Google Play (Android Market). If i use typical Gallery, the problem is the first item of gallery is at the center(it has big big space at the beginning and the same at the end). I tried some horizontal `listview` but it seem has problem with scrolling when i push my horizontal listview in another `scrollview` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6606840/1050058). In Google Play, the "gallery" doesn't have space at the beginning.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't approve suggested edits [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1142597). If needed, refer to [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/187824) for details.

Comment: @hims056 My bad.Maybe wrong tab. I searched but it can not reverse. If there's a way, please give me link.

Comment: Always read the comment from the editor and read the suggested edit carefully. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i  finished my project long ago and forgot close question. Using this [Android: Create an image Viewer using ViewPager.](http://life-optimized.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-create-image-viewer-using.html)

For future guests, you can see another training from Android Developer about ViewPager here:
[Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

use a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). it's used extensively in Google's in-house apps and works quite well for horizontal paging. it's also a pretty excellent replacement for [`TabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html).

[`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) is actually deprecated in favor of `ViewPager`.